# SQL Server- can a select query be executed to specify column names for the insert into command?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

So I'm trying to insert the same table into itself, but I have got a breakage because of repetition of primary keys. Hence, I'm thinking to insert the same rows without the primary key first, and then another query would insert an auto_increment primary key.

The following query breaks because of the primary key (obviously):

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

While the following query returns every field barring the primary key:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = table_name

EXCEPT

SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS [tc]
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE [ku] ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ku.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND ku.table_name = table_name
```

Now if I try to insert into a table not every column, the following is a proper syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (<column name list>) 
SELECT  <column name list> FROM table_name
```

But if I try to make it work for my case, the following query breaks because of not maintaining the table structure:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.drugs 
SELECT (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'drugs'

EXCEPT

SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS [tc]
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE [ku] ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ku.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND ku.table_name = 'drugs') FROM drugs;
```

The above breaks because I have not mentioned the column_names in the first line. Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft can you shed some light on it or give a close answer to it? I have never really worked with dynamic SQL, so I think I may be lost here.

Comment: What is the table definition?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
    (
        select concat('
        insert into drugs(',STRING_AGG(cast(name as nvarchar(max)), ', ') within group (order by column_id),')
        select ',STRING_AGG(cast(name as nvarchar(max)), ', ') within group (order by column_id),'
        from drugs')
        from sys.columns c
        where c.object_id = object_id('drugs')
          and c.is_identity = 0
   )
   print(@sql)
   exec (@sql)
```

Comment: this is a nice way to execute what exactly I want. Basically casting the results into column_names separated by commas. But this still doesn't account for the primary key constraint because the inside query still doesn't filter.

Comment: It filters identity columns.   But you should be able to modify the query if you need something different.